# How to copy a subset of files from a certain folder

Tags: filesystem

I have the following directory structure.

dirA/[fileA, someB, barC, fileD, someE, barF]
dirB/[fileA, barC, someE]

I want to copy only files from dirA to dirB which are already present in dirB. How do I do this selective copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for instance use the find command with the -exec option. You'd probably use some syntax like the following (has to be run in dirB, and be aware that it's recursive):

```
find ./ -type f -exec cp '../dirA/{}' ./ \;
```

The -type f tells find to only take into account regular files, the -exec says: run the following command on every file. The \; at the end terminates the command to be run. The {} is a placeholder that is replaced by the actual filename by find.
Check out the man page of find for details and other usage examples.

Here's what happens on my PC:

```
desktop:~$ mkdir dirA
desktop:~$ mkdir dirB
desktop:~$ cd dirA
desktop:~/dirA$ touch foo bar this
desktop:~/dirA$ cd ..
desktop:~$ cd dirB
desktop:~/dirB$ touch bar this
desktop:~/dirB$ find ./ -type f -exec cp -v '../dirA/{}' ./ \;

»../dirA/./this“ -> »./this“
»../dirA/./bar“ -> »./bar“
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be copying all files from dirA. I want to copy only files from dirA which are already present in dirB.

Comment: If you run it while you are in dirB it should really only copy files that are already there. You can add -v after cp to see which files it is copying. I'll update my above post with a usage example.